# How to stop running website copying task initiated in Plesk Panel?

Tags: ftp, plesk, transfer

I have started website copying to an external directory via FTP at Plesk Panel (Centos 7).
I wanted to stop it because it is too slow and will take it many days if I let it continue to run.
I have tried

1. Delete the running task from Plesk DB (from both longtaskparams and longtask)
2. Restart Plesk via SSH
3. service xinetd restart via SSH

All these did not stop the FTP Upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to find the process and kill it.

Use the command `sudo ps aux` to list all running processes.  To narrow it down `sudo ps aux | grep cp` might work.  It depends on how plesk implements this.

Once you find the process ID `sudo kill -9 (processID)`

If that isn't enough info to go on, you shouldn't be attempting this.